# For $x \in [0,1]$, find $F(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$ for each of the following functions $f$ defined on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $x \in [0,1]$, find $F(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$ for each of the following functions $f$ defined on $[0,1]$. In each case verify that F is continuous on $[0,1]$, and that $F'(x) = f(x)$ at all points where $f$ is continuous.

A) $f(x) = x^2 - 3x + 5$

B) $f(x) = x - \lfloor3x\rfloor$

C) $f(x) = x\lfloor3x\rfloor$

For A) I have
$\int_0^xt^2 - 3t + 5 = \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{3x^2}{2} + 5x = F(x)$

From looking at it I just said that it's continuous everywhere and for $F'(x) = f(x)$ I just showed that $\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = F'(x) = f(x)$

 Would that be sufficient?

As for B) and C) I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;x\in [0,1]\;\implies\;\lfloor3x\rfloor=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;0\le x<\frac13\\{}\\1&,\;\;\frac13\le x<\frac23\\{}\\2&,\;\;\frac23\le x<1\end{cases}\\{}\\\bullet&\;\;\;\int\limits_0^1=\int\limits_1^{1/3}+\int\limits_{1/3}^{2/3}+\int\limits_{2/3}^1\;\;\end{align*}$$

Comment: Then for B) Would I have $\frac{x^2}{2} - 2x + 1$ and for C) $x^2 - 5/18$?